# Angular mangles weird URLs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Our legacy website had URLs that looked like

`ouroldsite.com/Script?key=val1=val2`

These are now 301 redirected to:

`ournewsite.com/#!/Script?key=val1=val2`

When angular recieves these requests, it immediately changes the url to:

`ournewsite.com/#!/Script?key=val1`

You can see this in action on angulars website. Try visiting [angularjs.org/?key=val1=val2](https://angularjs.org/?key=val1=val2). The url will change immediately.

The url changes before routing resolved, so the controller registered to the path "/Script" will see the changed url.

Does anyone have any good ideas on how to fix this? Work arounds?

Comment: Isn't `=` an illegal character in a query string, that should be encoded as `%3D`?

Comment: Possibly, but it's there, and I need to deal with it. I'm leaning towards just rewriting location.hash before angular loads.